# how to convert json array to object in grails?

Tags: json, grails

I have a list as follows:

```
[
    attachmentId: 151,
    createdBy: 73,
    attachmentName: asd
],
[
    attachmentId: 152,
    createdBy: 73,
    attachmentName: pp
],
[
    attachmentId: 157,
    createdBy: 73,
    attachmentName: bacajh
],
[
    attachmentId: 158,
    createdBy: 73,
    attachmentName: sad
],
[
    attachmentId: 159,
    createdBy: 73,
    attachmentName: asd
],
[
    attachmentId: 160,
    createdBy: 73,
    attachmentName: p
],
[
    attachmentId: 161,
    createdBy: 73,
    attachmentName: 2
],
[
    attachmentId: 162,
    createdBy: 73,
    attachmentName: 1
]
```

How can I convert this json array to object in grails?

Comment: Into what Object? What you are showing it looks more to a Json already parsed than a raw Json. You can do something like list.collect { new Attachment(it.attachmentId, it.createdBy, it.attachmentName)} and you will have a list of Attachments (assuming that you have an Attachment class)

Comment: Yeah  i did what you told and it got me the result i wanted. AT first i was using JsonSlurper but it posed some unwanted issue which got resolved when i did what u said.

Answer (score 0):

You can use groovy's JsonSluper:

http://www.groovy-lang.org/json.html

```
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def object = jsonSlurper.parseText(...)
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a valid JSON object (the one you posted is not :-) you can use plain groovy for this:

```
def parsedJson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText("""[{
    "attachmentId": 151,
    "createdBy": 73,
    "attachmentName": "asd"
}]"""
)

assert parsedJson instanceof List
assert parsedJson.size() == 1
assert parsedJson.first() instanceof Map
assert parsedJson.first().keySet().size() == 3
assert parsedJson.first().attachmentId == 151
```

Comment: what i need to do is, be able to pass the jsonarray( the values that i get are the ones i mentioned above)that i get as an object, can you help me out with it??

Comment: The thing is that what you have in there is not a JSON array. In my answer I've shown you how to convert a valid JSON array (represented as a String) to a List. Isn't that what you need?